# Toggle border and select onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dictionary, sass

I am trying to use hooks to change react state onClick. I used .map to make a list of "cards" with different props and I want to make that into a form where I can click on 1 of the cards and the border/css will change and the card will be selected.

I'm not sure if I should put the hook for this in the page and pass to the component or put it directly in the component. (right now I have select in page and style in component, but it isn't working)

So far I can get the color to change on click, but if I click on another card it doesn't change the other one back. I have a few pages I have to do something similar to this on so any advice is appreciated!

Here is code for page:

```
const LemmeUpgradeYa = () => {
    const [path, setPath] = useState('/');

    const cardSelector = () => {
        // setPath('/${plans.plan}');
        console.log(AllPlans.AllPlans);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        cardSelector();
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Card>
                <style>
                    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Martel+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
                </style>
                <CardBody className="big-card-plan">
                    <h1 className="plan-title-one">Upgrade Plan</h1>
                    <Form>
                        {AllPlans.AllPlans.map((planItem) => (
                            <Cards onClick={cardSelector} key={planItem} {...planItem} />
                        ))}
                        <a href={path}>Continue</a>
                    </Form>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default LemmeUpgradeYa;
```

here is code for componenet:

```
const Cards = (plans) => {
    const [border, setBorder] = useState('profile-box-one');

    const cardSelector = () => {
        setBorder('profile-box-two');
        setPath('/${plans.plan}');
    };

    const selectChange = () => {
        setBorder('profile-box-one');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        selectChange();
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Card className={border} onClick={cardSelector} onChange={selectChange}>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="float-left max-width-plan">
                        <div className="plan-selector">Current Plan:</div>
                        <div className="center-text plan-font">{plans.plan}</div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="float-right padding-plan-top">
                        <Row>
                            <Col className="max-plan-width">
                                <p className="plan-description">{plans.description}</p>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <div className="plan-price">${plans.price} / month</div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Cards;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach is to have a state at `Parent` that holds the selected child id, you pass down to each `Child` the current selected and the function to select . At child you can compare if it was selected to pick the right CSS class.

obs: at `Cards` you are naming `props` as `plans`. though you can name however you want, it's standard to stay with the convention and call it as `props`.

below it's how you can handle the issue applied to your code:

```
const LemmeUpgradeYa = () => {
    const [pickedCard, setPickedCard] = useState(null);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Card>
                <style>
                    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Martel+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
                </style>
                <CardBody className="big-card-plan">
                    <h1 className="plan-title-one">Upgrade Plan</h1>
                    <Form>
                        {AllPlans.AllPlans.map((planItem) => (
                            <Cards pickedCard={pickedCard} setPickedCard={setPickedCard} key={planItem} plans={...planItem} />
                        ))}
                        <a href={path}>Continue</a>
                    </Form>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default LemmeUpgradeYa;


const Cards = ({ plans, pickedCard, setPickedCard }) => {

  const cardSelector = () => {
    setPickedCard(plans.plan);
      setPath('/${plans.plan}');
  };

  const selectChange = () => {
    setPickedCard(null);
  };

  return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Card className={`profile-box-${pickedCard ? 'two' : 'one' }`} onClick={cardSelector} onChange={selectChange}>
              <Row>
                  <Col className="float-left max-width-plan">
                      <div className="plan-selector">Current Plan:</div>
                      <div className="center-text plan-font">{plans.plan}</div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col className="float-right padding-plan-top">
                      <Row>
                          <Col className="max-plan-width">
                              <p className="plan-description">{plans.description}</p>
                          </Col>
                          <Col>
                              <div className="plan-price">${plans.price} / month</div>
                          </Col>
                      </Row>
                  </Col>
              </Row>
          </Card>
      </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```